# Unique smallest degree algebraic solution to polynomial ODE

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, at.algebraic-topology, polynomials, differential-equations

Let's assume we are given a degree $d$ polynomial VF as a map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$
$$f_j(x)=\sum_{i_{1},\dots,i_{n}=1}^{d}a^j_{i_{1},\dots,i_{n}}x_{1}^{i_{1}}\dots x_{n}^{i_{n}}$$

We call a solution $\dot{\gamma}_j(t)=f_j(\gamma(t))$ algebraic if
$$\exists j: f_j(\gamma(t))= \sum_{i_{1},\dots,i_{n}=1}^{d'}a_{i_{1},\dots,i_{n}}^{j}\gamma_1(t)^{i_{1}}\dots \gamma_n(t)^{i_{n}}=0 \quad \forall t$$

I want to proof the following: Let's assume we are given a degree $d'$ algebraic curve $\Gamma^{d'}$. Then, there exists a unique degree $d'-1$ polynomial VF $f^{d'}$ such that there is no other polynomial VF with equal or smaller degree having this curve as an invaraint algebraic curve.

---

**My intuition:**
$$
    F_1=(-x_2,x_1)
$$ $$
    F_2=(x_{1}-x_{1}^3-x_{2}-x_{1} x_{2}, x_{1}+x_{2}-x_{1}^2 x_{2} - x_{2}^3 )
$$ $$
    F_3 =(-2x_1^2-2x_1x_2-6x_2^2-6x_2+2,3x_1^2+4x_1x_2+6x_1+x_2^2-1)
$$
All these three polynomial ODEs have $\Gamma^2=x_1^1+x_2^2-1$ as invaraint algebraic curve. But only $F_1$ has degree 1 and I could not find any other degree one polynomial ODE with this invaraint algebraic curve.

---

**My proof idea:** Let $\Gamma^{d'}$ be the invaraint algebraic curve.
Then, setting the antisymmetric $S$-matrix and defining $f^{d'}$ by
$$
   S=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \quad \rightarrow \quad f^{d'}=S \nabla \Gamma^{d'}
$$
it also has $\Gamma^{d'}$ as invariant algebraic curve but is of degree $d'' = d'-1$

This is the existence proof. But I am stuck with the uniqueness. Maybe there is some argument from using irreducibility?